# How do I async/await a "main" function in Node.js, which uses a mysql query to drive output to multiple files?

Tags: mysql, node.js, async-await

I want to loop thru a list of employees and log relevant details to a separate file.
The list of employees comes from mysql and eventually their details will come from a request to the HR system.
The following code, with overall logger.end commented out, works and I get the relevant employee logs created.

```
/*
 *  40-mysql-2-fs.js
 *
 *  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 */
var fs = require('fs');

//File Write
const ctrlFileName = 'log41-EMP.txt';
var controlLogger = fs.createWriteStream(ctrlFileName, {
  flags: 'a' // 'a' means appending (old data will be preserved)
});

//mySQL
const mysql = require('mysql');
const conn = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'myuser',
  password: 'mypasswd',
  database: 'mydb'
});

conn.connect((err) => {
  if(err){
    console.log('Error connecting to Db');
    return;
  }
  console.log('Connection established!');
});

const mainResult = fnMain();

//controlLogger.end();
conn.end();

function fnMain() {
    conn.query('SELECT * FROM employees',
               (err,rows) => {
          if(err) throw err;

          console.log('Data received from Db:');
          var msg_no = 1;

          for (const row of rows) {
            console.log(msg_no,"-", row.forename,"#",row.surname);
            controlLogger.write(msg_no + '-' + row.forename + '#' + row.surname + '\r\n');

            var loopResult = loopthruFileTest(row);
            msg_no++;
          }

          controlLogger.write('END\r\n');
    });

}

function loopthruFileTest(row) {
  logFileName = 'log41-'+row.forename+'.txt';
  console.log('loopthruFileTest ',logFileName);

  //File Write
  var logger = fs.createWriteStream(logFileName, {
    flags: 'a' // 'a' means appending (old data will be preserved)
  });

  logger.write('Log: ' + logFileName + ' Surname: ' + row.surname + '\r\n');

  logger.end();
}
```

**I get the following error, if I un-comment `controlLogger.end();`**
I'm pretty sure its to do with the asynchronous nature of node ...

```
/home/ec2-user/AWS/r2data-index/03-load-transactions-pool/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
    at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:265:14)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:314:5)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/AWS/r2data-index/03-load-transactions-pool/40-mysql-2-fs.js:47:27)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/AWS/r2data-index/03-load-transactions-pool/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Query._callback (/home/ec2-user/AWS/r2data-index/03-load-transactions-pool/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:488:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/home/ec2-user/AWS/r2data-index/03-load-transactions-pool/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/home/ec2-user/AWS/r2data-index/03-load-transactions-pool/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:149:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (/home/ec2-user/AWS/r2data-index/03-load-transactions-pool/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:133:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/ec2-user/AWS/r2data-index/03-load-transactions-pool/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/home/ec2-user/AWS/r2data-index/03-load-transactions-pool/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
Emitted 'error' event on WriteStream instance at:
    at errorOrDestroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:108:12)
    at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:267:3)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:314:5)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/ec2-user/AWS/r2data-index/03-load-transactions-pool/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23) {
  code: 'ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END'
}
```

I have read lots of articles on promisess and async/await but nothing seems to work, so I need a check to make sure I'm going in the right direction.

Here is the SQL;

```
CREATE TABLE employees
(forename varchar(40)
,surname varchar(40)
,employee_id integer
);

INSERT into employees values ('Fred', 'Flintstone', 1);
INSERT into employees values ('Wilma', 'Flintstone', 2);
INSERT into employees values ('Barney', 'Rubble', 3);
INSERT into employees values ('Betty', 'Rubble', 4);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm pretty sure its to do with the asynchronous nature of node

You are right on the dot. Your write stream will throw the error you encountered if you try to write after you end the stream. Looking at your code, I see how a reasonable assumption about the order of execution is causing your error.

```js
conn.connect((err) => {...});

const mainResult = fnMain();

controlLogger.end();
```

at first glance, this is fine. connect to database, do stuff in main, then end the stream. this is not actually fine, however, because of the async stuff that happens in fnMain

```js
function fnMain() {
    conn.query('...', (err, rows) => {
        ...
        for (const row of rows) {
            controlLogger.write(...);
        }
    })

}
```

nodejs is not very smart; it won't know when your query will complete, nor when controlLogger.write is going to be called. All it knows is that you initiated a database connection, started exection of a query, and ended the logger write stream right away. from your current code, the sequence of events is

1. create mysql connection
2. start the query
3. end the logger write stream
4. write to write stream (after query finishes)

you are encountering your error because 4 is happening after 3 right now. the fix is moving this line

```js
controlLogger.end();
```

to right after the last controlLogger.write, like so:

```js
controlLogger.write('END\r\n');
controlLogger.end();
```

this guarantees that you end the controlLogger write stream after you finish the last write.

edit: Refactoring code a bit

```js
/*
 *  40-mysql-2-fs.js
 *
 *  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 */
const fs = require('fs');
const { promisify } = require('util');

//File Write
const ctrlFileName = 'log41-EMP.txt';
const controlLogger = fs.createWriteStream(ctrlFileName, {
  flags: 'a' // 'a' means appending (old data will be preserved)
});

//mySQL
const mysql = require('mysql');
const conn = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'myuser',
  password: 'mypasswd',
  database: 'mydb'
});

// new
const connect = connection => {
  return (promisify(connection.connect.bind(connection))()
    .then(() => console.log('Connection established!'))
    .catch(() => console.log('Error connecting to Db')))
};

const query = connection => {
  return promisify(connection.query.bind(connection))
};

const loopthruFileTest = async row => {
  const logFileName = 'log41-' + row.forename + '.txt';
  console.log('loopthruFileTest', logFileName)
  const logger = fs.createWriteStream(logFileName, { flags: 'a' })
  logger.write('Log: ' + logFileName + ' Surname: ' + row.surname + '\r\n');
  logger.end();
};

const closeConnection = connection => connection.end();

const fnMain = async () => {
  await connect(conn);
  const rows = await query(conn)('SELECT * FROM employees');
  console.log('Data received from Db:');
  let msg_no = 1;
  for (const row of rows) {
    console.log(msg_no, '-', row.forename, '#', row.surname);
    controlLogger.write(msg_no + '-' + row.forename + '#' + row.surname + '\r\n');
    await loopthruFileTest(row)
  }
  controlLogger.write('END\r\n');
  controlLogger.end();
  closeConnection(conn);
};

fnMain();
```

What changed: I created functions out of certain blocks and made them async. I also made fnMade async so I can await the async blocks I made.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, according to my understanding you are correct as to what is happening, however I added fnMain as I tried to get to grips with "await"ing the conn.query and loopthruFileTest, prior to this the controlLogger.end was immediately after the write.

Comment: `conn.query` by itself is not awaitable; however, if you are using node, you can use one of their utilities `const { promisify } = require('util')`. You can then await conn.query like so: `const rows = await promisify(conn.query.bind(conn))`

Comment: regarding loopthruFileTest, it seems like it is completely synchronous, so there is no need to await it

Comment: correction: `const rows = await promisify(conn.query.bind(conn))('SELECT...')`

Comment: good to know about promisify'ing query as I briefly mentioned loopthruFileTest is just a placeholder for a request sub function!

Comment: ah I see, in that case, let me revise my answer with some refactoring

Comment: This works as expected , thank you! One question; how would you modify to accept arguments for the sql statement. `const rows = await promisify(conn.query.bind(conn))('SELECT * from employess where surname = ?', [surname] )` doesn't work?

Comment: I would modify the `query` function like so:
`const query = connection => (...args) => {
  return promisify(connection.query.bind(connection))(...args)
};`
which is syntactically equivalent to
`const query = connection => {
  return promisify(connection.query.bind(connection))
};`

Comment: ill make edits in the answer that will work for the original solution and your comment

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your fnMain() function is being executed before the con.connect() function completes due to the asynchronous node.js event loop. Also you conn.end() function is not waiting for fnMain() to resolve, closing the db connection before your sql query executes which is why it is throwing the write after end error.

```
var fs = require('fs');

//File Write
const ctrlFileName = 'log41-EMP.txt';
let controlLogger;

const loopthruFileTest = async row => {
  const logFileName = 'log41-'+row.forename+'.txt';
  console.log('loopthruFileTest ',logFileName);

  //File Write
  var logger = await fs.createWriteStream(logFileName, {
    flags: 'a' // 'a' means appending (old data will be preserved)
  });

  await logger.write('Log: ' + logFileName + ' Surname: ' + row.surname + '\r\n');

  logger.end();
  return row
}


const db = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'localhost',
      user: 'myuser',
      password: 'mypasswd',
      database: 'mydb'
});

const fnMain = () => new Promise((res) => {
  //connect to the database
  res(db.connect())
})
.then(async () => {
  //establish the control logger
  controlLogger = await fs.createWriteStream(ctrlFileName, {
    flags: 'a' // 'a' means appending (old data will be preserved)
  });
  return
})
.catch(e => {
 console.log('Error connecting to Db');
})
.then(()=> {
 console.log('Connection established!');
 return db.query('SELECT * FROM employees')
})
.then(rows => {
  console.log('Data received from Db:');

  //map rows into promises and resolve all
 return Promise.All(rows.map((row, rowIndex) => new Promise((res) => {
  console.log(rowIndex,"-", row.forename,"#",row.surname);
  controlLogger.write(rowIndex + '-' + row.forename + '#' + row.surname + '\r\n');
  res(loopthruFileTest(row))
    })
 ))
})
.then(resultArray => {
 controlLogger.write('END\r\n');
})
.finally(() => {
  // .finally() will always execute even if there are uncaught errors in the promise chain
  controlLogger.end();
  db.end();
})
```

Comment: Hi, this looks like what I'm looking for but ... I get the following error and I can't follow it thru! `/home/ec2-user/AWS/r2data-index/03-load-transactions-pool/42-stackoverflow-answers.js:56
 })
  ^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1070:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1120:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    ...
`

Comment: @chris-j Yes, sorry i probably should have tested it out in a code editor before submitting the answer. It was just missing a ")" after Promise.All. Code has been updated, give it a try now.